# Message: Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to run the following application in CodeIgniter, I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: views/blog.php
Line Number: 1
```

I've been trying to figure it out for almost an hour and I can't get it to work. My view looks like this:

```
<?php foreach($data->result() as $row): ?>
<h1><?php echo $row->title; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row->post; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller {  
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $data = $this->db->get('posts');

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('blog', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `$data` does not set, did you really set this variable?

Comment: $data = $this->db->get('posts');
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change your controller and view

the array you send throught data should be like this:

```
$data['post'] = $this->db->get('posts');
```

and in your view:

```
<?php foreach($post->result() as $row): ?>
<h1><?php echo $row->title; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row->post; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

codeiginter sends variables to view using $data array. If you want to send something to a view, put inside to $data as $data['key'] = $val;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$blog` instead of `$data` in the first line of your view.
I'm not sure but you assign `$data` to a key called `blog` in your controller...

Answer (score 0):

The variables must be passed to the view as key-value pairs inside an array. [Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) this is explained.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error notice is not originating on your controller but on your view (blog.php). You forgot to pass $data to the view. You should restructure the variable being passed to your view to something like this:

```
$data['data'] = $this->db->get('posts');
$this->load->view('blog', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

please structure your post model like this

```
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();

        }




    public function get_posts(){




            $query=$this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();







    }

    }
```

and your post controller like  this

```
      public function index()
            {

           $data['posts']=$this->Post_model->get_posts();  





        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

and in your view file echo content this way :)

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>


<h3><?php echo  $post['post_title'];?></h3>
<small><?php echo  $post['post_date'];?></small>
<p><a href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['post_title']);?>">Read more</a></p>

<?php   endforeach;?>
```

Comment: So basically, your answer is to confirm the accepted answer and the only useful line is :     $data = $this->db->get('posts');

Answer (score 0):

In the controller file, if you want to eliminate this error, write

```
$data['variable-name']
```

then in the view file, instead of using `$data`, use `$variable_name`
i.e

```
<?php foreach($variable_name->result() as $row): ?>
```