# Codeigniting doesn't take my data?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am completly new and have readed the tutorials about codeigniter.

My question is i keep getting this:

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Notice

 Message: Undefined variable: data

 Filename: views/welcome_message.php

 Line Number: 70
```

And my controller "welcome.php":

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = "Hello world";
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}

 }
```

My view is

I am using the "$data" in the view-load, but i keep getting this message, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905403/message-undefined-variable-data

Answer (score 3):

The keys you put into the `$data` inside your controller will became variables (with [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)) in your views. So in your example, the:

```
// controller
$data['title'] = 'hello world';
```

Will be available in your view as:

```
// view
<?php print $title ?>
```

You don't need to prefix everything with `$data` in your views.

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is just the "highway" as it were -- the route the data takes to get to the view. Technically it is just an array used to transport the variables set to the view.

Once the data is in the view, you reference it by the `$data`'s key. So, in your case, in the view, you would reference the title as `$title`.

This array can be named whatever you want, but the convention is to use `data`.

So, in my controller I could do:

```
$stuff['title'] = "This is my title";
$this->load->view('my_view', $stuff);
```

And in the view:

```
echo $title;//echo's out "This is my title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is probably trying to use $data...which is not defined since it doesn't exist as $data['data'] in the array being sent to the view.